# New templates and updating subsites in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

Problem: We creates projectsites from a custom template.
The customer asked about the ability to create a new template with changes and apply the new template to the earlier created projects (subsites).
As far as I know there is no possible way to do this.

And by updating contenttypes and creating new view you still dont get it applied to all the involved libraries.

Does anyone have a good workaround or suggestions on how to handle this, or should I tell my customer it isnt possible?

Answer (score 0):

Change the definition of your site will definitely not apply to the old sites.
There isn't magical workaround to resolve this issue. Basically, you could :

- Write some PowerShell Script to upgrade list if you changed the definition. This is a common solution to apply change after a first creation.
- Manage manually the layouts if you change the UI. (In PowerShell, it's pretty hard)

As you said, you should warn your customer that every modification'll need some maintenance. You can help him to save times with some tools but no more. (Sounds better that saying it's impossible. :) )